# Add constraint to view progmatically

Tags: android-constraintlayout

I have inflated the following view inside a constraint layout.
View :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:text="menu"/>
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>
</LinearLayout>
```

View added to contraint layout using the following code:

```
ConstraintLayout constraintLayout  =  findViewById(R.id.root);
                View inflatedLayout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, constraintLayout, false);                   constraintLayout.addView(inflatedLayout);
```

The view moves to the top of the screen because there are no constraints. It overlaps the toolbar which is at the top of the layout.  The toolbar is simply constrained to be at the top of the parent with its id as `android:id="@+id/toolbar"`

How do I add the constraints progmatically so that the inflated view is constrained below the toolbar.
I have used constraint set to add the constraint to the inflated view like this:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(PaymentStatus2.this);

                ConstraintLayout constraintLayout  =  findViewById(R.id.nested);

                View inflatedLayout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, constraintLayout, false);
                constraintLayout.addView(inflatedLayout);
                ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
                 set.connect(constraintLayout.getId(),ConstraintSet.TOP,inflatedLayout.getId(),ConstraintSet.TOP,50);
            set.connect(constraintLayout.getId(),ConstraintSet.START,inflatedLayout.getId(),ConstraintSet.START,0);

                set.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

In the first connect line I am connecting the parents top to the inflated view's top and setting a margin of 50dp which should server my purpose of keeping it below the toolbar which is 50dps in height but that does not reflect in the layout. 
Thinking that the view needs atleast two contaraints i make the second connection still it is not working.
 This is how it looks like :

https://ibb.co/r2wK83V

the inflated layout is still moving to the top as if there are no constrainsts on it.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else stuck with this I found out how it is done.
Inflate the layout add it then clone the layout, then you need to connect all four constraint ends then only will it work.

The connect function takes five params
 (i)the view id of the view,(ii)the constraint direction, (iii)the other view id ,(iv)the constraint direction, (v)margin

```
 ConstraintLayout constraintLayout  =  findViewById(R.id.nested);
                View inflatedLayout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, constraintLayout , false);
                inflatedLayout.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(0,0));
                constraintLayout.addView(inflatedLayout,0);
                ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
                set.clone(constraintLayout);
                set.connect(inflatedLayout.getId(),ConstraintSet.TOP,toolbar.getId(),ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,8);
                set.connect(inflatedLayout.getId(),ConstraintSet.START,constraintLayout.getId(),ConstraintSet.START,8);
                set.connect(inflatedLayout.getId(),ConstraintSet.END,constraintLayout.getId(),ConstraintSet.END,8);
                set.connect(inflatedLayout.getId(),ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,swipeRefreshLayout.getId(),ConstraintSet.TOP,8);
                set.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```